# Getting Consistent Video Delivery on All Platforms with Video JS

Tags: html, mobile, mp4, video.js, http-live-streaming

So I've been working at this for a while now.

I'm trying to get consistent video delivery on across platforms using Video JS and I'm at my wits end.

I'm hosting from a shared GoDaddy server, and actually not having any issues with bandwidth delivery from the server, it can handle 200 concurrent connections.

I'm wanted to use a single video source, an M3U8 playlist using Videojs-contrib-hls, but for some reason it isn't working on Windows desktop browsers. I'll be hittin up their Git Hub Today too.

I'm trying to use an MP4 Fallback, but I'm not getting totally consistent behavior when I try to use the "sourceOrder" option. I'm currently running a mobile redirect to get mobile users to the version with the M3U8 playlist.

Here's an Example of my setup:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/video.js"></script>
        <script src="js/dash.all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/videojs-dash.js"></script>
        <script src="js/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

    <video id="6032017" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9" data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 2, 4] }' poster="images/6032017/6032017.jpg" controls>
<source src="images/6032017/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL"/>
<source src="images/6032017/6032017.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
                <script>
    var player = videojs('6032017');
    player.play();
    </script>
```

I'm also trying to use the Videojs-contrib-dash and can't get that to work at all, but thats a whole nother issue.

And finally, the Speed Control won't appear on the mobile version I have that just has the M3U8 as the source.

Oh, and the Videos won't autoplay on my new LG Stylo 2. I just get a black screen.

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you could point us to a public URL where we could play/debug with what you have so far? (e.g. I'd be willing to then prototype something similar, in effort to come further up to speed with your use-cases.)

Comment: Sure, 

walukungfu.org/test.html.

this'll give you an idea. I have longer videos that have issues when I try to use the seek bar through them on desktop MP4

Comment: Excellent, thx.  'show source' on it works fine...nice clean code!  [ It will probably be a day or three, before I get my equiv prototype code working and have (hopefully) some useful feedback for you.    Stay tuned. ]

Comment: Hey, Dave, I decided to load the VideoJS and HLS Contrib with CDN and things are playing back fine now. I'm gonna close this question, but thanks for your help.

If you're still feeling froggy the playbackRates option isnt working on my android chrome browser.

Have a good one.

Comment: Cool, thx!  BTW, I'm also loading those from CDN (which I've always preferred) and in my prototyping, I'm getting an error on 'contrib' one. (This is on Win-10 in Chrome.)  And, I found this...hope it might be useful.) https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/1124